# Capistrano Deploy asks for Username for Git but moves to new line before I can enter it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, capistrano

When deploying my rail 3 app with Capistrano It gets to the step where capistrano executes this command:

```
   * executing "if [ -d /var/www/appname/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /var/www/dflabs1/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origi
n && git reset -q --hard d0a1373a3634935de1a75f377698ba53574fe580 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q https://github.com/username/dflabs1.git /va
r/www/appname/shared/cached-copy && cd /var/www/appname/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy d0a1373a3634935de1a75f377698ba53574fe580; fi"
    servers: ["11.10.1.162"]
Password: 
    [11.10.1.162] executing command
 ** [11.10.1.162 :: out] Username for 'https://github.com':
```

The problem is that when it outputs "Username for 'https://github.com'" , the cursor jumps to a new line without letting me enter the username. If I try and enter the username on the new line the deploy just does nothing. This is happen on an Ubuntu 12.04 desktop to an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I tried adding the 'set :scm_username' option to deploy.rb but that had no effect. I tried in the Ubuntu terminal and in the Terminal view inside Aptana.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the SSH-Key of your Deployment-Server into GitHub.

You can do this here: [SSH Keys](https://github.com/settings/ssh).
You can find the tutorial for SSH-Keys (Github) here: [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

[EDIT]
Actually I just did it myself and checked the output.

Are you sure you set your `set :repository,  "git@github.com:[GitHub-User]/[GitHub-Repository-Name].git"`in the deploy.rb correctly?

because your

```
else git clone -q https://github.com/username/dflabs1.git
```

looks here like

```
else git clone -q git@github.com:[GitHub-User]/[GitHub-Repository-Name].git
```

Comment: It does the same thing when using SSH or HTTP auth. I might decide to deploy from local instead of github master, the server is in house and the repository is small.